# Printing from inheritance classes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

say I have this code, I would like to know what would the code in the main would print.The output.  At first I thought that when the first command would be called, the default constructor of Base would be called then would print "from Base" and after that the constructor of A would be called and then it would print "from A"".
but I'm not sure because I think there is a chance that because when we perform this command, "Base* base = new A()", I suspect slicing might me happening, so I would like your help on the print output.

At the end when I delete base, the print from that one should be as ordered I think:
It would only call the destructor of Base and from "from Base".
so because in the main we add a new from the derived class to the base class, I'm not sure. 
thank you.

```
class Base {
    virtual void method() {
         std::cout << "from Base" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    virtual ~Base() {
         method();
    }
    void baseMethod() {
         method();
    }
}

class A: public Base {
    void method() {
        std::cout << "from A" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    ~A () { method();}
};


int main (void) {
    Base* base = new A();
    base -> baseMethod();
    delete base;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try it? Your code has a few minor errors that mean it wouldnt compile. So I'm guessing you have not? You will not get slicing, it occurs when trying to use polymorphism with values (as opposed to pointers or references) e.g. `Base b = A();`.

Comment: *"the default constructor of Base would be called then would print "from Base"* Why again would you expect that? The default constructor of `Base` is implicitly defined and doesn't print anything. Neither does the default constructor of `A`.

Comment: I know the code has minor bugs, the next questions are to eliminate the flaws.. but first I need to say what it prints with the flaws. :).

Comment: I think it should print, from A, from A, from Base

Comment: *"It would only call the destructor of Base"* False. You've made `~Base` virtual - the whole point of that is to allow correctly destroying an instance of derived class via a pointer to base.

Comment: you are searching for is C++ book

Answer (score 0):

Start with this slightly modified version of your code and step through.

It should help you to understand how it works.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {

// since we're going to call this from the derived class's method(), it must at least be protected    
protected:
    virtual void method() {
         std::cout << "from Base" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    virtual ~Base() {
        std::cout << "calling ~Base()\n";
        // calling a virtual method from a base class constructor or destructor may not give you the result you expect.
        // at this point, the derived class is gone. the standard says that you will actually call Base::method, not A::method
         method();
    }
    void baseMethod() {
         method();
    }
};

class A: public Base {
    void method() {
        std::cout << "from A" << std::endl;
        Base::method();
    }
public:
    ~A () {
        std::cout << "calling ~A()\n";
        method();
        }
};


int main (void) {
    Base* base = new A();
    base -> baseMethod();
    delete base;
}
```

expected output:

```
from A
from Base
calling ~A()
from A
from Base
calling ~Base()
from Base
```